# Why are there multiple node.js processes when I start my app on a single core machine

Tags: node.js, memory, process

**Situation**

I'm actually analyzing my node.js application on my server and local machine for memory optimization and found something which is confusing.

If I run my app locally (mac osx) and see a single process in the systems activity monitor — That's what I expect because there are no child processes launched with e.g. cluster.

But when I run the app on my staging maching (AWS Ubuntu EC2 Micro Instance) I see via `htop` there are five related processes running my app instead of the expected one process.

[image: htop screenshot process list]

**Analysis**

Each process uses exact the same memory.
After I had a look into the processes parents `htop` showed up, there's one node parent with four children.

[image: htop process hierarchy]

I've tried to kill one child process which cause a complete crash (when running without [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)) so it seems each process is required.

**Question**

Why is there a difference between the operating systems and why does node obviously need multiple processes on the ubuntu system.

Thanks for any help understanding it.

Comment: V8 is spinning multiple threads for it's own needs (4 of them)

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Thanks. And do you know why there's only one on osx although it's the 'bigger' machine?

Comment: Probably it just coutns them differently. Here you have 1 process but with 5 threads. Probably os x doesn't count the number of threads

Comment: Hmm ok I've checked it on osx there are 9 threads.

Comment: Strange... but of what I know v8 creates several threads to handle GC and background work, while the actual nodejs still runs in one thread as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node has only a single process but it has lots of threads. The standard `top` including the OS X process monitor displays processes. By default `htop` displays threads. You can switch the display mode by pressing `H`.

V8 has its own threads - including the GC, Node can have its own threads in some cases, libuv launches `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` threads - these are the threads for the async I/O. There are lots of threads in a Node executable.